# Google Analytics creating an experiment (AB Testing)

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to create an experiment in Google Analytics. However, all of the [documentation available](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745216) online seems to be out of date. I can get to the `Behaviour -> Experiments` area, which seems to be the only mention of experiments on the site, but then there's no option to create one.

[image]

Does anyone know how to start an experiment, or if this feature has been disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a permissions problem: if you don't have permissions to create an experiment, the button doesn't exist.